# Reload falhando em alguns momentos

Tags: query

Fiz um script para setar uma imagem como capa, o script funciona perfeitamente e programei o mesmo para realizar um reload no retorno, mas estranhamente esse reload falha em alguns momentos, sem motivo aparente.

O script é esse:

```
    $(function() {
    $("[name='btncapa']").on('click', function(e) {
        var id_equipe = $(this).attr('id_equipe');
        var id_equipe_img = $(this).attr('id_equipe_img');

        var $el = $(this);
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Confirma a marcação de capa para foto?",
            title: "Capa",
            buttons: {
                success: {
                    label: "Sim",
                    className: "btn-success",
                    callback: function() {
                        $.getJSON('CapaFotoEquipe.php', {
                            id_equipe: id_equipe,
                            id_equipe_img: id_equipe_img
                        }, function(resposta) {
                            $("#diverro").html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>ERRO!</strong> " + resposta.erro + "</div>");
                        }); 
                        // RELOAD NO RETORNO                                                    
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Não",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function() {}
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ponha o   location.reload(true); dentro do function(resposta)

Comment: Olá @pho3nix, já tinha feito esse teste o script não faz nada.

Comment: Pelo javascript ser assincrono, coloque na dentro da function callback() do get. Já tentou com window.location.reload(true)? @adventistapr